# position:absolute for footer not working as expecting

Tags: css, footer

I have googled it but couldn't find any working solution; As a below example  the `position:absolute` does not set the footer at the bottom of page

```css
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <h2>Fixed/Sticky Footer Example</h2>
  <p>The footer is placed at the bottom of the page.</p>

  <h2>Fixed/Sticky Footer Example</h2>
  <p>The footer is placed at the bottom of the page.</p>

  <h2>Fixed/Sticky Footer Example</h2>
  <p>The footer is placed at the bottom of the page.</p>

  <h2>Fixed/Sticky Footer Example</h2>
  <p>The footer is placed at the bottom of the page.</p>

  <h2>Fixed/Sticky Footer Example</h2>
  <p>The footer is placed at the bottom of the page.</p>

  <h2>Fixed/Sticky Footer Example</h2>
  <p>The footer is placed at the bottom of the page.</p>

  <h2>Fixed/Sticky Footer Example</h2>
  <p>The footer is placed at the bottom of the page.</p>

  <h2>Fixed/Sticky Footer Example</h2>
  <p>The footer is placed at the bottom of the page.</p>

  <h2>Fixed/Sticky Footer Example</h2>
  <p>The footer is placed at the bottom of the page.</p>

  <h2>Fixed/Sticky Footer Example</h2>
  <p>The footer is placed at the bottom of the page.</p>

  <h2>Fixed/Sticky Footer Example</h2>
  <p>The footer is placed at the bottom of the page.</p>

  <h2>Fixed/Sticky Footer Example</h2>
  <p>The footer is placed at the bottom of the page.</p>

  <h2>Fixed/Sticky Footer Example</h2>
  <p>The footer is placed at the bottom of the page.</p>

  <div class="footer">
    <p>Footer</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

If I scroll it, I will get:

[image]

I want the footer get pinned at the bottom of the page, who can I do this?

Comment: Try `position: fixed` instead

Comment: @Maharkus no I don't want a fixed footer I just want it to get pinned down at the bottom

Comment: Remove `position: absolute;`?

Comment: Like at the bottom of all the text? Why do you use `position: absolute` at all then?

Comment: @j08691 then If my page has less content than page's height then it will not be at the bottom of the page!

Comment: And we should know you want that how? You didn't specify the behavior you wanted from your footer in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: fixed` instead of `position: absolute`, please check working example below based on your code.

```css
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <h2>Fixed/Sticky Footer Example</h2>
  <p>The footer is placed at the bottom of the page.</p>

  <h2>Fixed/Sticky Footer Example</h2>
  <p>The footer is placed at the bottom of the page.</p>

  <h2>Fixed/Sticky Footer Example</h2>
  <p>The footer is placed at the bottom of the page.</p>

  <h2>Fixed/Sticky Footer Example</h2>
  <p>The footer is placed at the bottom of the page.</p>

  <h2>Fixed/Sticky Footer Example</h2>
  <p>The footer is placed at the bottom of the page.</p>

  <h2>Fixed/Sticky Footer Example</h2>
  <p>The footer is placed at the bottom of the page.</p>

  <h2>Fixed/Sticky Footer Example</h2>
  <p>The footer is placed at the bottom of the page.</p>

  <h2>Fixed/Sticky Footer Example</h2>
  <p>The footer is placed at the bottom of the page.</p>

  <h2>Fixed/Sticky Footer Example</h2>
  <p>The footer is placed at the bottom of the page.</p>

  <h2>Fixed/Sticky Footer Example</h2>
  <p>The footer is placed at the bottom of the page.</p>

  <h2>Fixed/Sticky Footer Example</h2>
  <p>The footer is placed at the bottom of the page.</p>

  <h2>Fixed/Sticky Footer Example</h2>
  <p>The footer is placed at the bottom of the page.</p>

  <h2>Fixed/Sticky Footer Example</h2>
  <p>The footer is placed at the bottom of the page.</p>

  <div class="footer">
    <p>Footer</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```